# Issue with bootstrap columns while nesting inside columns

Tags: html, css, web, web-applications, bootstrap-grid

The layout of page is miss-placed when columns are nested inside another column

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="col-6">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to add a `<div class="row">` before the nested column too.

Comment: I am working in big project and it is so difficult and time taking so how we can overwrite bootstrap grid system and that could work with same code?

Comment: If you are working on a big project, where are the big developers that need to work on it? :) I would ask you to follow the normal approach instead of overwriting it. The DOM structure needs to be changed not the CSS.

Comment: I have an answer below your question. This saves you from having to overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Example]

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**An advanced way:**

```
<div class="container bg-primary" style="width: 800px; height: 100px; ">
    <div class="row ml-1 h-100">
        <div class="col-10 ml-0 my-auto h-75 container bg-danger">
            <div class="row ml-1 h-100">
                <div class="col-8 ml-0 my-auto h-75 container bg-warning">
                    <div class="row ml-1 h-100">
                        <div class="col-6 ml-0 my-auto h-75 container bg-success">
                            <div class="row ml-1 h-100">
                                <div class="col-4 ml-0 my-auto h-75 container bg-dark">

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]